# Writing a program that compresses char characters with bit-wise masking. Getting Segmentation fault and struggling to spot the bug

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

new to C and looking for guidance. I am writing code to bit-wise mask characters. Program changes 8 bits to 7 bit by dropping the unnecessary "0" at the end of the binary number. I am getting a segmentation fault error and don't see where I am going out of bounds. Any guidance/advice is appreciated, thanks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void compress(int origfile, int newfile);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  char *newfilename = strcat(argv[1], ".z827");
  char *filename = strdup(argv[1]);
  int starterfile = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY);
  int newfile = creat(newfilename, 0644);
  if (argc !=2 )
  {
    printf("Usage: z827 filename\n");
    exit(1);
  }

  printf("Filename is: %s\n", filename);

  if (starterfile == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot open %s\n", argv[1]);
    exit(1);
  }
  else
  {
    compress(starterfile, newfile);
  }

  return 0;
}
void compress(int origfile, int newfile )
  {
    unsigned int compbuffer;
    unsigned char index;
    int i;
    int counter = 0;
    int filesize = 10000;
    char *buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * filesize);
    int filechars = read(origfile, buffer, filesize);

    while (filechars > 0)
    {
      index = buffer[i];
      compbuffer += index;

      for (i = 0; i < filechars - 1; i++)
      {
        index = buffer[i];
        compbuffer = compbuffer | (index << (7 - counter++));
        index = (compbuffer & 255);
        if (counter < 8)
        {
          write(newfile, &index, 1);
          compbuffer = compbuffer >> 8;
        }
        else
        {
          counter = 0;
        }
      }
      write (newfile, &compbuffer, 1);
    }

    if(filechars == -1)
    {
      perror("Unable to read file.");
    }

    free(buffer);
  }
```

Comment: Now would be a good time to learn to use a debugger. What is the exact line of code that triggers the seg fault? The debugger will tell you that instantly.

Comment: The very first `strcat` goes out of bounds.

Comment: It's 7-bit packing, relies on the fact that most text-files use only first 127 ASCII chars, not extended ASCII. Mostly used in GSM SMS protocols.

Comment: @user3386109 It goes out of bounds when ```char *newfilename = strcat(argv[1], ".z827"); //Filename for the compressed file.``` ?

Comment: Yes, `strcat` doesn't do any memory management. It expects the first parameter to point to a buffer that's big enough to hold the concatenated string. `argv[1]` is only guaranteed to be big enough to hold the string that it started with. You can't add another 5 characters to it without risking a buffer overflow.

Comment: BTW, you need to verify that `argc` is at least 2 **before** you even think about using `argv[1]`. The code is using `argv[1]` three times before it gets around to checking `argc`. That'll definitely result in a segfault if the user forgets to enter the filename.

Comment: @user3386109 Would ```char *newfilename = strcat(argv[1]+5, ".z827");``` Cut it?

Comment: @kaylum I am using the GNU debugger. when I run the program it just states that I have a seg fault. Won't let me use the "step into/ step over" functions

Comment: No, `argv[1] + 5` is a pointer to the fifth character of whatever string the user entered. You need to crack open a book on C and start reading. Unlike some other languages, you can't learn C by guessing.

Comment: I hope you are passing the command line arguments while executing the binary. Put a check for argv array or better check the argc value in the beginning itself before assigning values to pointers. You are doing it but much later in the code.

Comment: Probably because the first thing you do is undefined. The arguments passed can be modified, but not expanded (where would they get space?) One can copy the string to a bigger buffer. Either a static size, in which case, you should check if the buffer is large enough, or a dynamically-allocated size, checking if allocation failed.

Answer (score 0):

My compiler told me immediately about error you will get to once you fix the whole filename massaging at the start

```
int i;   <<<<======================
int counter = 0;
int filesize = 10000;
char *buffer = malloc(sizeof *buffer * filesize);
int filechars = read(origfile, buffer, filesize);

while (filechars > 0)
{
  index = buffer[i];   <<<<<<<<<=======
```

you need to initialize i to 0

compbuffer too

Your file name code can be fixed like this

```
   char suffix[] = "z827";
   int len = strlen(argv[1]) + sizeof(suffix) + 1; 
   char *fname = malloc(len);
   sprintf(fname, "%s.%s", argv[1], suffix);
```

check argc first tho